# Java - Convert Unix epoch time to date

Tags: java

I need to convert some epoch time stamps to the real date and have used some of the methods I found on stack overflow, but they give the wrong answer.

As an example, one date is "129732384262470907" in epoch time, which is "Mon, 20 Jan 6081 05:24:22 GMT" using http://www.epochconverter.com/

However, my code generates: "Wed Dec 24 14:54:05 CST 19179225"

```
  String epochString = token.substring(0, comma);
  long epoch = Long.parseLong(epochString);
  Date logdate = new Date(epoch * 1000);
  BufferedWriter timewrite = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempfile, true));
  timewrite.write(logdate);
  timewrite.flush();
  timewrite.close();
```

The initial timestamp is in miliseconds, which in the examples I saw here I am supposed to multiply by 1000.

If I don't multiply by 1000, I get: "Mon Aug 08 01:14:30 CDT 4113025"

Both of which are wrong.

So where have I made my error?

Answer (score 2):

129732384262470907 is actually in *microseconds* since the epoch if it's meant to be 6081, so you need to *divide* by 1000 if that's real input.

Note that `epochconverter.com` doesn't even handle that value - it only allows you to enter `129732384262470` which it then treats as *milliseconds* since the epoch.

You need to multiply by 1000 if your data is *seconds* since the epoch. Basically all you need to know is that Java expects milliseconds since the epoch; the rest should be plain sailing, assuming you know what your input data actually means.

If you could provide your *real* data, and what it's meant to represent, it's probably going to be easy to fix your problems.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about epochconveter.com  I would have never figured that out on my own.  And as you can see from my post below, between your two answers, I was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully, epochconverter.com truncated that number because it was too long for the entry field.

I suggest you print the current value of `System.currentMillis()` to see what approximate range a "current" epoch-based timestamp has, and re-scale your input number to match. I think you'll probably have to divide by 1000.

In fact, looking closer, if you divide by 10,000, you get 1297323842624, which comes out to a date in 2011. So it's not at all clear what units the number you've given are in.

Comment: And you're awesome!!  That one change made it work properly.  Thanks again, and you're correct the epochconverter.com was giving an incorrect value the real time is "Sun Jan 19 23:24:22 CST 6081"

Comment: Really? You're expecting the year 6081?

Comment: Of course, I'm a time traveler.  I just need to get back to 6081 and the primitive systems available are very frustrating.  [/joke]  Sorry, pasted the wrong one, the correct one is this: "Thu Feb 10 01:44:02 CST 2011"  I had to divide by 100,000